# Move ssd drive with win7 and ubuntu 12.04 already installed to new laptop

Tags: 12.04, dual-boot, ssd

I want to move my ssd drive that has dual boot with win 7 and ubuntu 12.04 installed to my new laptop.

I'm using grub for the dual boot.

I was hoping life would be easier with just physically moving the drive but it turned to be much harder.

The new laptop comes with an internal HDD which I formatted to NTFS.
Now I have boot problem, I was able to load ubuntu but I had no network.

I've set the AHCI mode in bios.
Now I'm using ubuntu from the live cd and everything works fine.

Please help me out with this one, what steps should I take to get a working setup?
I can live with reinstalling win 7 but I can't afford losing my current ubuntu installation.

I appreciate any help.

10x

Answer (score 0):

It is entirely possible to move the hard drive to another computer as ubuntu seems almost universally portable (except between architectures). If you are having trouble with network, as that seems to many times be the problem anyway, see if it is a broadcom adapter, in which case you need to reinstall the bcmwl-kernel-source driver or whatever driver you are using, even if you came from a broadcom card before

Answer (score 0):

> I can't afford losing my current ubuntu installation

What does that mean in practice?

Just moving the SSD over is probably prone to generate loads of issues - depending on the hardware differences between the machines.

I generally make sure that /home is saved - maybe keep /etc/* too - to have it as something to pick cherries from. I would not consider it be possible use a copy straight out of the box for a new computer. Some things in /home may well fall into the same category too.

Moving Windows is definitely not easy in this way, none of the software harddisk / partition copying has this as a viable option AFAIK. I haven't even tried moving between something else than partitions and harddisks on the same computer.

The best - as in "least error prone" - is to move data by hand, then reinstall all software and work from there - moving data back into place, considering differences between software used and possibly also keeping an eye on versions.